# Привилегии при запуске через VS выше чем через админа

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

```
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);


HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, entry.th32ProcessID);

        char path[MAX_PATH];

        GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, path, MAX_PATH);

        cout << path << endl;

        cout << "th32ProcessID=" << entry.th32ProcessID << endl;

        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
}

CloseHandle(snapshot);
```

Если скомпилировать этот код, то при запуске через visual studio я могу видеть процессы порождаемые системой, а если запустить его же, но без vs, но через админа, то системные процессы не видно.

Каким образом можно добиться картины как при запуске через  visual studio?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в код проверку на наличие SeDebugPrivilege у вашего процесса. Думаю, из Студии она будет, а от админа - нет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, добавление привилегии все исправило)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно дать SeDebugPrivilege процессу :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // token handle
    LPCTSTR Privilege,      // Privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // TRUE to enable.  FALSE to disable
)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tpPrevious;
    DWORD cbPrevious = sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES);

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, Privilege, &luid)) return FALSE;

    // first pass.  get current privilege setting
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &tp,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        &tpPrevious,
        &cbPrevious
    );

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS) return FALSE;

    // second pass.  set privilege based on previous setting
    tpPrevious.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;

    if (bEnablePrivilege) {
        tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes |= (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED);
    }
    else {
        tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes ^= (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED &
            tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes);
    }

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &tpPrevious,
        cbPrevious,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}


HANDLE enableDebugPrivilege()
    {
        HANDLE hToken;

        if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, &hToken))
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
            {
                if (!ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation)) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, &hToken)) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        // enable SeDebugPrivilege
        if (!SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE))
        {
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            return 0;
        }

        return hToken;
    }

    void dissableDebugPrivilege(HANDLE hToken)
    {
        SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, FALSE);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
```